# Error with my UPDATE mysql query, with a lot of join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, syntax-error

When I try the following query :

```
UPDATE cache_implementation
SET parent_through_compared_id = ncp.nid, parent_through_feature_id = nfp.nid
FROM cache_implementation n
INNER JOIN cache_compare nc ON n.compared_id = nc.nid
INNER JOIN cache_implementation ncp ON (nc.nid = ncp.compared_id AND n.feature_id = ncp.feature_id)
INNER JOIN cache_feature nf ON n.feature_id = nf.nid
INNER JOIN cache_implementation nfp ON (nf.nid = nfp.feature_id AND n.compared_id = nfp.compared_id)
```

I have the following error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM cache_implementation n INNER JOIN cache_compare nc ON n.compared_id = nc' at line 3

Through this query, I try to update two fields with value located in some other table, by making a mass update query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using used in `TSQL`. Here's for `MySQL`.

```
UPDATE cache_implementation n
       INNER JOIN cache_compare nc 
             ON n.compared_id = nc.nid
       INNER JOIN cache_implementation ncp 
             ON (nc.nid = ncp.compared_id AND n.feature_id = ncp.feature_id)
       INNER JOIN cache_feature nf 
             ON n.feature_id = nf.nid
       INNER JOIN cache_implementation nfp 
             ON (nf.nid = nfp.feature_id AND n.compared_id = nfp.compared_id)
SET    parent_through_compared_id = ncp.nid, parent_through_feature_id = nfp.nid
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL multi-table update statement, the `SET` clause follows the table references. (This differs from the syntax used in other databases.)

To fix your statement, delete that first line, move the line with SET to the bottom, qualify the column references with the table alias, and change `FROM` to `UPDATE`. Voila.

`UPDATE`<strike>`cache_implementation`

`FROM`</strike> `cache_implementation n`
`INNER JOIN` ...
`INNER JOIN` ...

 
`SET n.col = expr, n.col2 = expr`

[Multi-table update syntax documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html)